# Monotouch Binding Categories (Using Category Attribute)

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am trying to bind the lib XYOrigami but seem to be hitting a few issues. The current documentation on [Xamarin.com docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries/binding_types_reference_guide) advises using the Category attribute, i get an error advising this could not be found and resolving the reference adds a using to System.ComponentModel. The binding project builds without issue but the two methods are not available on any UIView objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace XYOrigami
{
  delegate void OrigamiAnimationCompleted (bool finished);

  [BaseType (typeof(UIView))]
  [Category]
  interface Origami{

      [Export ("showOrigamiTransitionWith:NumberOfFolds:Duration:Direction:completion:")]
      void ShowOrigamiTransition (UIView view, int folds, float duration, XYOrigamiDirection direction, OrigamiAnimationCompleted completed);

      [Export ("hideOrigamiTransitionWith:NumberOfFolds:Duration:Direction:completion:")]
      void HideOrigamiTransition (UIView view, int folds, float duration, XYOrigamiDirection direction, OrigamiAnimationCompleted completed);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the documentation is a little ahead of itself there. This is going to be added to a future version of MonoTouch but isn't currently released yet (hence it not finding the correct Category attribute)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you have a link on how to do this currently?